# Finding if someone got a new role on discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to give a suffix every members on my server. The nickname should be for example **Name (role)**.
I tried the simple

```
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", function(oldMember, newMember){
    //Here the setting
});
```

But it wasn't good. Can you help me?
I think, it should be like this:
client on guildMemberUpdate:
check if someone's role is xy:
give him a suffix, like name (role).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are assigning the role programatically it would be easier if you handle the name change of the role in the same part of the code since you already know which role is the new one, if this is not the case you are right for using the event, what you want is to find the new role that has been added and change the name of the member after

```js
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
  // Get the role which has been added
  const newRole = newMember.roles.cache
    .filter(r => !oldMember.roles.cache.has(r.id))
    .first()

  // Change username
  newMember.setNickname(`${newMember.displayName} (${newRole.name})`)
})
```

[See Collection methods](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection)

Comment: guildMemberUpdate event is also emmited when user got new nickname, removes roles, etc. Don't forget to return if newRole is null

Comment: This system won't always work because of the 32 character nickname limit, of course it's going to be rare that it happens but it's a possibility nonetheless

Comment: I think that is out of the scope of the question, there's more things to keep in mind like permissions etc